# Ramda.js - How to make R.merge point free - 2 functions with same dataset

Tags: ramda.js

Given the below code snippet that uses Ramda.js, are there multiple ways of making `parseDetails` point free? If so, is there an "ideal" way of doing it?

```js
const someData = {
  products: [{
    stockId: 123,
    name: "chocolate",
    translatedTags: {
      wasPrice: "Was 10"
    }
  }]
}


const getProductData = R.pipe(
  R.pathOr([], ['products', 0]),
  R.pick([
    'stockId',
    'name']
  )
);


const getProductTags = R.pipe(
  R.pathOr([], ['products', 0, 'translatedTags'])
);


const parseDetails = (data) => R.merge(
  getProductData(data),
  getProductTags(data)
);

parseDetails(someData);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways I can think of, but by far the best is to use [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift).  The way I think of using `lift` is that it takes a function which works on *values* and returns an equivalent function which works on *containers of those values*.

And functions that return those values can be thought of as containers.  So we can do it like this:

```js
const getProductData = pipe (
  pathOr ([], ['products', 0]),
  pick ([
    'stockId',
    'name']
  )
)
// `pipe` not necessary here
const getProductTags = pathOr ([], ['products', 0, 'translatedTags'])


const parseDetails = lift (merge) (getProductData, getProductTags) 


const someData = {products: [{stockId: 123, name: "chocolate", translatedTags: {wasPrice: "Was 10"}}]}
console .log (parseDetails (someData))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, pathOr, pick, lift, merge} = R </script>
```

And if you have no other need for `getProductData` or `getProductTag`, you can inline them in the function:

```js
const parseDetails = lift (merge) (
  pipe (pathOr ([], ['products', 0]), pick (['stockId', 'name'])), 
  pathOr ([], ['products', 0, 'translatedTags'])
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Scott Sauyet. I'll continue my studies and will have a look at more examples of the lift usage.